# Issue when routing a page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having trouble with this script

```
// App.js ( shrink )

var controller = require('./controller');

app.get('/', controller.index);

app.get('/home', controller.home);

// /controller/index.js

var meta = {

    title: 'index',
    description: ''
}

exports.index = function(req,res){

    res.render('index', {

        meta: meta
    });
}

// /controller/home.js

var meta = {

    title: 'glibet',
    description: ''
}

exports.home = function(req,res){

    res.render('home', {

        meta: meta
    });
}
```

Its returning me this Error: "Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]"

Strangely enough it works just fine if i let *app.get('/', controller.index);* alone without the *home* route

I've tried a couple of corrections/alternatives in the code maintaining the system its way of invoking *controller/files* but it doesn't seem to fix the code, i will really appreciate any help.

PS: I'm trying to avoid setting a variable to each controller file, avoiding something like this code;

```
var homeController = require('./controllers/home');
var userController = require('./controllers/user');

app.get('/', homeController.index);
app.get('/login', userController.getLogin);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you require `./controller`, Node first looks for a file called `controller`. Failing that, it looks for a file called `index.js` inside the directory `controller`.

You are not requiring every file in a directory by using `require()` in this manner.

You could use a plugin such as [require-dir](https://www.npmjs.org/package/require-dir) for this purpose. However, my recommendation would be to require each file separately, so that you know exactly what you are making available to your page-- this prevents side effects where you accidentally leave a file in your routes directory that you didn't want required by your main application controller.

Comment: Thanks, but your recommendations doesn't help with what i'm trying to achieve, That is a way to avoid setting a variable for each controller file.

Comment: The usual way I handle that is to pass `app` into the function I'm `require`ing. So, `require('./routes/foo')(app);` and then call `app.get()` inside my individual routefiles.

Comment: could you explain a little more? i'm starting to learn javascript and i don't quite understand what (app) does in your code.

Comment: Here's a [Gist with some examples](https://gist.github.com/sethkinast/d7c7938cc9dd529099c9).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `require` a directory of js files as an object. If you want to keep all of your controller files separate but have them represented in one object in your app, you could do something like this:

```
// /controller/controllers.js

var home = require('./home');
var index = require('./index');
module.exports = {
    home: home.home,    
    index: index.index
}
```

By requiring './controller/controllers' you could keep all of your controller endpoints organized in different files while accessible in one object.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer would solve my problem but i wonder if there's a easier/simpler way of doing it.

Comment: I don't think that you're going to be able to group the functionality from different files much more easily than that. You could devise some crazy fs-based solution that creates an object containing your endpoints by looping through the files in your controllers directory, but I don't think 'easier' describes that.